# What's the difference between /tmp and /swap and /system/volatile in Solaris 11

Tags: solaris, swap, tmpfs

My Solaris 11 `df` output has different swap entries

```
root@hostname:/# df -h | egrep "tmp|swap"
/tmp                   108G   5.1G       103G     5%    /tmp
swap                   150G   119G        31G    80%    /system/volatile
swap                   110G    79G        31G    73%    /apptmp
```

Also `swap -lh` shows a different output altogether:

```
root@hostname:/# swap -lh
swapfile             dev    swaplo   blocks     free
/dev/swap             -         8K      48G      48G
```

How can I interpret this output? Which swap space is really in use?

Comment: You have no `/swap`. It does not exist.

Comment: Please add the output of `zpool list`, `zfs list` and `swap -s` to your question.

Answer (score 1):

My guess, because the names are different from the system that I use (Debian).

- `/tmp` is a temporary directory (not a guess).
- `/tmp` is part of a real filesystem, persistent over reboots.
- `/system/volatile` is backed by swap, it is not persistent over boots.
- `swap` is the filesystem-type used for swap, similar to `tmpfs`.
- `/apptmp` see explanation for `/system/volatile`.
- `/dev/swap` is probably a link to the swap file/partition. Try `ls -dl /dev/swap` to find out.
- `/swap` does not exist, see outputs in your question.

Answer (score 1):

`swap`is the background storage for the various memory based filesystems.

If you like to see the filesystem type, you could call:

```
mount -p
```

to get a `vfstab` like output for the current mount state.